# Looping Through Each Word In Word Document Using Docx Library

Tags: novacode-docx

I am trying to make a small program to apply autocorrect changes to an exiting document. I am using the docX library. My question is, how do you iterate (or loop) through each word in the document, using the docX library, to check if it needs to be corrected or not (I have already inserted all auto correct entries in a `list<T>`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this...

```js
DocX document = DocX.Load( <document path> );

foreach(Novacode.Paragraph item in document.Paragraphs) {
  
  // use this if you need whole text of a paragraph
  string paraText = item.Text;
  
  // use this if you need word by word
  foreach(var data in item.MagicText) {
    
    string word = data.text;
  }
}
```

Comment: MagixText is available in the Paragraph class in the DocX libary. Please refer this [link]http://docx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#DocX/Paragraph.cs

It gets the formatted text value of a given Paragraph.