# Docx - Removing section of document

Tags: c#, regex, novacode-docx

Is there a way to remove sections of a document where i can specify the beginning and ending tags?

i need a way that i can remove a section of the document by passing in both my start and end catches, (@@DELETEBEGIN and @@DELETEEND)

for example i have this in my document:

> Hello, welcome to this document
>
> @@DELETEBEGIN{Some values to check in the code}
>
> Some text that will be removed if the value is true
>
> @@DELETEEND
>
> Final Line

Comment: I don't think there is an easy why of doing this or a way at all.

Comment: i may have found a solution, check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to delete text from @@DELETEBEGIN to @@DELETEEND, where @@DELETEBEGIN is not at the beginning of a `Paragraph` and @@DELETEEND is not at the end of a `Paragraph`, this code should work.

```
DocX document = DocX.Load("C:\\Users\\phil\\Desktop\\text.docx");
bool flag = false;
List<List<string>> list1 = new List<List<string>>();
List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
foreach (Novacode.Paragraph item in document.Paragraphs)
{
    //use this if you need whole text of a paragraph
    string paraText = item.Text;
    var result = paraText.Split(' ');
    int count = 0;
    list2 = new List<string>();
    //use this if you need word by word
    foreach (var data in result)
    {
        string word = data.ToString();
        if (word.Contains("@@DELETEBEGIN")) flag = true;
        if (word.Contains("@@DELETEEND"))
        { 
            flag = false;
            list2.Add(word);
        }
        if (flag) list2.Add(word); 
        count++;
    }
    list1.Add(list2);
}
for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count(); i++)
{
    string temp = "";
    for (int y = 0; y < list1[i].Count(); y++)
    {
        if (y == 0) 
        {
            temp = list1[i][y];
            continue;
        }
        temp += " " + list1[i][y];                   
    }
    if (!temp.Equals("")) document.ReplaceText(temp, "");
}
document.Save();
```

I have to give some credit to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28422248/looping-trough-each-word-in-word-document-using-docx-library) for looping through each word.

Comment: Quite a late response but I have to say thank you! I started having issues with the code I used previously on some customer documents. this method is much more robust and works better in my situation. thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, I was working with Novacode quite a lot over the previous summer and dealt with a lot of different things like this.

Answer (score 1):

I think i have found a solution to this, at least it works for me, please let me know if there is anything i can do better:

the deleteCommand would be the @@DELETEBEGIN string and the deleteEndCommand would be the @@DELETEEND

```
    private void RemoveSection(DocX doc, string deleteCommand, string deleteEndCommand)
    {
        try
        {
            int deleteStart = 0;
            int deleteEnd = 0;

            //Get the array of the paragraphs containing the start and end catches
            for (int i = 0; i < doc.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
            {
                if (doc.Paragraphs[i].Text.Contains(deleteCommand))
                    deleteStart = i;
                if (doc.Paragraphs[i].Text.Contains(deleteEndCommand))
                    deleteEnd = i;
            }

            if (deleteStart > 0 && deleteEnd > 0)
            {
                //delete from the paraIndex as the arrays will shift when a paragraph is deleted
                int paraIndex = deleteStart;
                for (int i = deleteStart; i <= deleteEnd; i++)
                {
                    doc.RemoveParagraphAt(paraIndex);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah that works if you want to delete something from the beginning of  `Paragraph[i]` to the end of `Paragraph[i]`. If you want something deleted within middle of `Paragraph[i]` to a different location in another `Paragraph[i]`, it won't work. If your solution solves your problem, that is good.

Comment: Yes that is true, for that i think its not possible due to the structure of the document, but this code works for me as in my case the delete strings will always be seperate paragraphs